# oldstr(None) raises exception: cannot convert 'NoneType' object to bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When porting PY2 to PY3 I'm using the [future library](https://pypi.org/project/future/). I try to `str(None)` and it fails, but both py2 and py3 support `str(None)`.
Is this a python bug or the desired behaviour?

Try this:

```
In[6]: from past.builtins import str as oldstr
In[7]: oldstr(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../venv/py3_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-42dcefbf9e2f>", line 1, in <module>
    oldstr(None)
TypeError: cannot convert 'NoneType' object to bytes
In[8]: str(None)
Out[8]: 'None'
```

Comment: I have a theory, but I'm not sure about it. Since oldstr should also handle byte arrays, and None symbols null termination, perhaps it fails to allocate an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

As you know str is the in-built function of python:

the in-built str function doesn't throw errors but,

when you use the same function str with an alias name.

another way I can explain it:

```
import past

### past.builtins.str() is from module

### str() is the in-built function of python when you type "str()" in your code it always uses the str() in-built 

### You can see that the str in-built function is colored in syntax highlighting.


past.builtins.str() != str() # in-built str()
```

At last, the code ran correctly.

There is an error in past.builtins.str() not in in-built str()

to use it as str change the code to:

```
from past.builtins import str as str
```

or

```
from past.builtins import str # same thing
```

oldstr(None) # expected Error: No functions like this.

str(None) # expected Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../venv/py3_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-42dcefbf9e2f>", line 1, in <module>
    str(None)
TypeError: cannot convert 'NoneType' object to bytes
```